# Javascript Promise.all - how can I make this existing function synchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, synchronous, chaining

I have a function which works fine when its ran synchronously, but as soon as I make it asynchronous it fails to work because it is returning true before all images are loaded.

Here is the original function which existed:

```
if (window.num_alt > 0) {
  var div = document.getElementById('productImageLarge');

  if (div) {
    var html = '';
    colour = colour || '';

    var tmp = getTemplate('image_holder');
    if (!tmp) { tmp = 'image_holder is missing<br>'; }

    // num_alt same number as images - use this for the loop
    for (var i=0; i<num_alt-0+1; i++) {
      var tmp1 = tmp;
      tmp1 = tmp1.replace(/\[xx[_ ]image\]/ig, imagename+colour+alt_ext[i]);
      tmp1 = tmp1.replace(/\[xx[_ ]img_no\]/ig, i);
      html += tmp1;

      // at the end of the loop
      if (i == num_alt) {
        imagesDone = true;
      }
    }
    div.innerHTML = html;
  }
}
return imagesDone;
```

Basically it takes the num_alt images set in a variable (set to 8) and fills in a JS template. Once its at the end of the loop I have another function on an interval testing whether imagesDone == true. Once it is set to true, the function fires and the image slider kicks in.

I wanted to lazy-load the images, and for some reason the current function wouldn't allow me to do this without trying to load images that return a 404. So I converted the function to use promises which calls itself until all images are processed (removed the for loop) and this has worked for a while, but its using async:false....

```
var imagesDone = false;
//console.log("Create Image");

if (window.num_alt > 0) {
  var div = document.getElementById('productImageLarge');

  if (div) {
    var html = '';
    colour = colour || '';

    var tmp = getTemplate('image_holder');
    if (!tmp) { tmp = 'image_holder is missing<br>'; }

    var i = 0;
    var promises = [];
    function ajax_data() {

      promises.push($.ajax({
        url: thisUrl+'product-image.php?size=large&image=/'+imagename+colour+alt_ext[i]+'.jpg',
        method: 'post',
        data: promises,
        async : false,
        success: function (resp) {
          if (i<=num_alt) {
            var tmp1;
            tmp1 = tmp;
            tmp1 = tmp1.replace(/\[xx[_ ]image\]/ig, imagename+colour+alt_ext[i]);
            tmp1 = tmp1.replace(/\[xx[_ ]img_no\]/ig, i);
            html += tmp1;
            div.innerHTML = html;
            i++;

            ajax_data();
          }
        }
      }))
    }

    Promise.all([ajax_data()])
      .then([imagesDone = true])
      .catch(e => console.log(e));

  }
}
return imagesDone;
```

If I remove the async:false, imagesDone is returned too soon and the slider function kicks in to early. Can anyone help me understand how to make this work in a synchronous / chained fashion? I've been trying for a while but just can't seem to get it to work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't make asynchronous call synchronous - except you can with $.ajax, but you don't want to ... so ... what?

Comment: You don't even need `Promise.all` since you're dealing with ONE asynchronous method ... just return `$.ajax( ...` and in the calling code, use `.then` method of promise (because $.ajax returns a promise)

Comment: The issue is conceptual - stop thinking you need to return the value. Instead return the promise (i.e. result of the ajax call) as Jaromanda says, and let the calling code handle the promise being resolved, and get the value it needs. Although you maybe need Promise.all still (and it would be the promise from that which you would return), I think Jaromanda has missed that you might call the ajax method several times depending on the number of images.

Comment: If you make the function asynchronous (which you should), then you won't be able to return a value like a conventional synchronous function. Instead, call `Promise.all()` and then just return that. Let the code that *calls* your function tack a `.then()` onto the returned promise to handle the images when they all load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do, your code looks like part of a function that already doesn't do what you want it to do. Maybe the following will work for you:

```
var Fail = function(reason){this.reason=reason;};
var isFail = function(o){return (o||o.constructor)===Fail;};
var isNotFail = function(o){return !isFail(0);};

//...your function returning a promise:
var tmp = getTemplate('image_holder') || 'image_holder is missing<br>';
var div = document.getElementById('productImageLarge');
var html = '';
var howManyTimes = (div)?Array.from(new Array(window.num_alt)):[];
colour = colour || '';
return Promise.all(//use Promise.all
  howManyTimes.map(
    function(dontCare,i){
      return Promise.resolve(//convert jQuery deferred to real/standard Promise
        $.ajax({
          url: thisUrl+'product-image.php?size=large&image=/'+imagename+colour+alt_ext[i]+'.jpg',
          method: 'post',
          data: noIdeaWhatYouWantToSendHere//I have no idea what data you want to send here
          // async : false //Are you kidding?
        })
      ).catch(
        function(error){return new Fail(error);}
      );
    }
  )
).then(
  function(results){
    console.log("ok, worked");
    return results.reduce(
      function(all,item,i){
        return (isFail(item))
          ? all+"<h1>Failed</h1>"//what if your post fails?
          : all+tmp.replace(/\[xx[_ ]image\]/ig, imagename + colour + alt_ext[i])
            .replace(/\[xx[_ ]img_no\]/ig, i);
      },
      ""
    );
  }
).then(
  function(html){
    div.innerHTML=html;
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this worked very well, but it seems to be a bit temperamental around this line of code which sets the number of ajax calls "(div)?Array.from(new Array(2)):[];".  The previous function used window.num_alt - which is set to 8, but it also gave 404's for images that weren't found. If a 404 is returned will the promise never resolve? I have added a catch to the end but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Jonathan The line `(div)?Array.from(new Array(2)):[];` should be: `(div)?Array.from(new Array(window.num_alt)):[];`. Any ajax call that fails will create a fail object and the line `all+"<h1>Failed</h1>"//what if your post fails?` should deal with that. I have updated the code since the `.fail` should come directly after `$.ajax()`

Comment: As soon as I get a fail the code never gets to the "ok worked" and it doesn't get to the last .then function where the div.innerHTML is set. I've added some logs to test.

Comment: @Jonathan If you are using new jQuery you may try `.catch` instead of `.fail` because older versions of jQuery don't have deferred behaving like promises. If you are using older version of jQuery you can try real promises, I've updated the answer using real promises.

Comment: This needs to work in IE9,10,11 so I guess this isn't the way forward. Not sure if its possible to load the images asynchronously and achieve what I need for those browsers. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in the code above, indicating that you may need to understand better how [Promises](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-promises-for-dummies) work. Your function should probably return the Promise so that the caller handle the asynchronicity on their side.

So either use:

```
return Promise.all(promises);
```

or:

```
return Promise.all(promises).then(function() { return true; })
```